# GPUImage add hue/color adjustments per-RGB channel (adjust reds to be more pink or orange)

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, gpuimage

Stumped trying to adjust the hue of a specific channel (or perhaps, more specifically, a specific range of colors - in this case, reds). Looking at the hue filter, I thought maybe I might get somewhere by commenting out the green and blue modifiers, impacting the changes on only the red channel:

```
 precision highp float;
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform mediump float hueAdjust;
 const highp  vec4  kRGBToYPrime = vec4 (0.299, 0.587, 0.114, 0.0);
 const highp  vec4  kRGBToI     = vec4 (0.595716, -0.274453, -0.321263, 0.0);
 const highp  vec4  kRGBToQ     = vec4 (0.211456, -0.522591, 0.31135, 0.0);

 const highp  vec4  kYIQToR   = vec4 (1.0, 0.9563, 0.6210, 0.0);
 const highp  vec4  kYIQToG   = vec4 (1.0, -0.2721, -0.6474, 0.0);
 const highp  vec4  kYIQToB   = vec4 (1.0, -1.1070, 1.7046, 0.0);

 void main ()
 {
     // Sample the input pixel
     highp vec4 color   = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

     // Convert to YIQ
     highp float   YPrime  = dot (color, kRGBToYPrime);
     highp float   I      = dot (color, kRGBToI);
     highp float   Q      = dot (color, kRGBToQ);

     // Calculate the hue and chroma
     highp float   hue     = atan (Q, I);
     highp float   chroma  = sqrt (I * I + Q * Q);

     // Make the user's adjustments
     hue += (-hueAdjust); //why negative rotation?

     // Convert back to YIQ
     Q = chroma * sin (hue);
     I = chroma * cos (hue);

     // Convert back to RGB
     highp vec4    yIQ   = vec4 (YPrime, I, Q, 0.0);
     color.r = dot (yIQ, kYIQToR);
//  -->    color.g = dot (yIQ, kYIQToG); 
//  -->   color.b = dot (yIQ, kYIQToB);

     // Save the result
     gl_FragColor = color;
 }
);
```

But that just leaves the photo either grey/blue and washed-out or purplish green. Am I on the right track? If not, how can I modify this filter to affect individual channels while leaving the others intact?

Some examples:

Original, and the effect I'm trying to achieve:

[image] [image]

(The second image is almost unnoticeably different, however the red channel's hue has been made slightly more pinker. **I need to be able to adjust it between pink<->orange**).

But here's what I get with B and G commented out:

(Left side: <0º, right side: >0º)

[image] [image]

It looks to me like it's not affecting the hue of the reds in the way I'd like it to; possibly I'm approaching this incorrectly, or if I'm on the right track, this code isn't correctly adjusting the red channel hue?

(I also tried to achieve this effect using the `GPUImageColorMatrixFilter`, but I didn't get very far with it).

Edit: here's my current iteration of the shader using @VB_overflow's code + GPUImage wrapper, which is functionally affecting the input image in a way similar to what I'm aiming for:

```
#import "GPUImageSkinToneFilter.h"

@implementation GPUImageSkinToneFilter

NSString *const kGPUImageSkinToneFragmentShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

 // [-1;1] <=> [pink;orange]
 uniform highp float skinToneAdjust; // will make reds more pink

 // Other parameters
 uniform mediump float skinHue;
 uniform mediump float skinHueThreshold;
 uniform mediump float maxHueShift;
 uniform mediump float maxSaturationShift;

 // RGB <-> HSV conversion, thanks to http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/07/27/rgb-to-hsv-in-glsl
 highp vec3 rgb2hsv(highp vec3 c)
{
    highp vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
    highp vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));
    highp vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));

    highp float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
    highp float e = 1.0e-10;
    return vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);
}

 // HSV <-> RGB conversion, thanks to http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/07/27/rgb-to-hsv-in-glsl
 highp vec3 hsv2rgb(highp vec3 c)
{
    highp vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
    highp vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
    return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
}

 // Main
 void main ()
{

    // Sample the input pixel
    highp vec4 colorRGB = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

    // Convert color to HSV, extract hue
    highp vec3 colorHSV = rgb2hsv(colorRGB.rgb);
    highp float hue = colorHSV.x;

    // check how far from skin hue
    highp float dist = hue - skinHue;
    if (dist > 0.5)
        dist -= 1.0;
    if (dist < -0.5)
        dist += 1.0;
    dist = abs(dist)/0.5; // normalized to [0,1]

    // Apply Gaussian like filter
    highp float weight = exp(-dist*dist*skinHueThreshold);
    weight = clamp(weight, 0.0, 1.0);

    // We want more orange, so increase saturation
    if (skinToneAdjust > 0.0)
        colorHSV.y += skinToneAdjust * weight * maxSaturationShift;
    // we want more pinks, so decrease hue
    else
        colorHSV.x += skinToneAdjust * weight * maxHueShift;

    // final color
    highp vec3 finalColorRGB = hsv2rgb(colorHSV.rgb);

    // display
    gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColorRGB, 1.0);
}
);

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization and teardown
@synthesize skinToneAdjust;
@synthesize skinHue;
@synthesize skinHueThreshold;
@synthesize maxHueShift;
@synthesize maxSaturationShift;

- (id)init
{
    if(! (self = [super initWithFragmentShaderFromString:kGPUImageSkinToneFragmentShaderString]) )
    {
        return nil;
    }

    skinToneAdjustUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"skinToneAdjust"];
    skinHueUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"skinHue"];
    skinHueThresholdUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"skinHueThreshold"];
    maxHueShiftUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"maxHueShift"];
    maxSaturationShiftUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"maxSaturationShift"];

    self.skinHue = 0.05;
    self.skinHueThreshold = 50.0;
    self.maxHueShift = 0.14;
    self.maxSaturationShift = 0.25;

    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Accessors

- (void)setSkinToneAdjust:(CGFloat)newValue
{
    skinToneAdjust = newValue;
    [self setFloat:newValue forUniform:skinToneAdjustUniform program:filterProgram];
}

- (void)setSkinHue:(CGFloat)newValue
{
    skinHue = newValue;
    [self setFloat:newValue forUniform:skinHueUniform program:filterProgram];
}

- (void)setSkinHueThreshold:(CGFloat)newValue
{
    skinHueThreshold = newValue;
    [self setFloat:newValue forUniform:skinHueThresholdUniform program:filterProgram];
}

- (void)setMaxHueShift:(CGFloat)newValue
{
    maxHueShift = newValue;
    [self setFloat:newValue forUniform:maxHueShiftUniform program:filterProgram];
}

- (void)setMaxSaturationShift:(CGFloat)newValue
{
    maxSaturationShift = newValue;
    [self setFloat:newValue forUniform:maxSaturationShiftUniform program:filterProgram];
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% set on making this work with GPUImage or are you open to other libraries that may be low low level?

Comment: Can't see it getting much more low-level than OpenGL-ES? Nothing exists like GPUImage anyway.

Comment: Yeah, well I mean moving to something like ImageMagick, it's a lot more heavy duty than GPUImage in terms of filters, coloration, etc, etc, at least from my experience anyway.

Comment: Yeah not going that route - hundreds of hours invested in GPUImage

Comment: Yep, no problem, I have the answer already in ImageMagick, but not a problem, good luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made an example on [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4lsXDf). Use latest Chrome to see it, on my side it does not work on Firefox or IE because it uses a video as input.

After some experiments it seems to me that for red hues to be more "pink" you need to decrease the hue, but to get more "orange" you need to increase saturation.

In the code I convert to HSV instead of YIQ because this is faster, makes tweaking saturation possible and still allow to tweak hue. Also HSV components are in a [0-1] interval, so no need to handle radians.

So here is how this is done :

1. You choose a reference hue or color (in your case a red hue)
2. Shader compute the "distance" from current pixel hue to ref hue
3. Based on this distance, decrease hue if you want pink, increase saturation if you want orange
4. It is important to note that hue behaves differently than saturation and  value: it should be treated as an angle (more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)).

The reference hue should be hardcoded, chosen by user (by color picking image), or found by analysing image content.

There are many different possible ways the compute the distance, in the example I chose to use the angular distance between hues.

You also need to apply some kind of filtering after computing the distance to "select" only closest colors, like this [gaussian like function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-x*x*50.0%29%20from%200%20to%201).

Here is the code, without the ShaderToy stuff:

```
precision highp float;

// [-1;1] <=> [pink;orange]
const float EFFECT_AMOUNT = -0.25; // will make reds more pink

// Other parameters 
const float SKIN_HUE = 0.05;
const float SKIN_HUE_TOLERANCE = 50.0;    
const float MAX_HUE_SHIFT = 0.04;
const float MAX_SATURATION_SHIFT = 0.25;

// RGB <-> HSV conversion, thanks to http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/07/27/rgb-to-hsv-in-glsl
vec3 rgb2hsv(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
    vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));
    vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));

    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
    float e = 1.0e-10;
    return vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);
}

// HSV <-> RGB conversion, thanks to http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/07/27/rgb-to-hsv-in-glsl
vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
    vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
    return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
}

// Main
void main ()
{   
    // Sample the input pixel
    vec4 colorRGB = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

    // get effect amount to apply
    float skin_tone_shift = EFFECT_AMOUNT;

    // Convert color to HSV, extract hue
    vec3 colorHSV = rgb2hsv(colorRGB.rgb);  
    float hue = colorHSV.x;

    // check how far from skin hue
    float dist = hue - SKIN_HUE;        
    if (dist > 0.5)
        dist -= 1.0;
    if (dist < -0.5)
        dist += 1.0;
    dist = abs(dist)/0.5; // normalized to [0,1]

    // Apply Gaussian like filter
    float weight = exp(-dist*dist*SKIN_HUE_TOLERANCE);  
    weight = clamp(weight, 0.0, 1.0);

    // We want more orange, so increase saturation
    if (skin_tone_shift > 0.0)
        colorHSV.y += skin_tone_shift * weight * MAX_SATURATION_SHIFT;
    // we want more pinks, so decrease hue
    else
        colorHSV.x += skin_tone_shift * weight * MAX_HUE_SHIFT;

    // final color
    vec3 finalColorRGB = hsv2rgb(colorHSV.rgb);     

    // display
     gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColorRGB, 1.0);
}
```

**More Orange:**

[image]

**More Pink:**
[image]

**--EDIT--**

It seems to me that you are not setting the uniform values in your ObjectiveC code. If you forget this shader will get zero for all those.

Code should look like this :

```
- (id)init
{
    if(! (self = [super initWithFragmentShaderFromString:kGPUImageSkinToneFragmentShaderString]) )
    {
        return nil;
    }

    skinToneAdjustUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"skinToneAdjust"];
    [self setFloat:0.5 forUniform:skinToneAdjustUniform program:filterProgram]; // here 0.5 so should increase saturation

    skinHueUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"skinHue"];
    self.skinHue = 0.05;
    [self setFloat:self.skinHue forUniform:skinHueUniform program:filterProgram];

    skinHueToleranceUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"skinHueTolerance"];
    self.skinHueTolerance = 50.0;
    [self setFloat:self.skinHueTolerance forUniform:skinHueToleranceUniform program:filterProgram];

    maxHueShiftUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"maxHueShift"];
    self.maxHueShift = 0.04;
    [self setFloat:self.maxHueShift forUniform:maxHueShiftUniform program:filterProgram];

    maxSaturationShiftUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"maxSaturationShift"];    
    self.maxSaturationShift = 0.25;        
    [self setFloat:self.maxSaturationShift forUniform:maxSaturationShiftUniform program:filterProgram];

    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Looks really slick! I'll spend some time today fiddling with this and see what I can make happen. Cheers!

Comment: Finally got this integrated into GPUImage, but it's not affecting the image quite like I'm trying to do. Instead of adjusting the reds between pink and orange, it's affecting them the same way it does in my q - between pink and green. Thoughts?

Comment: Ah, and for that matter, even playing around with the hue shift on shadertoy has the same effect - so I need to figure out a way of calculating a hue between pink and orange, rather than pink and green. What about finding a way to 'tint' the reds (now that we've isolated them) rather than a hue shift?

Comment: It seems that changing the hue of "dark reds" cause them to turn green, so I changed the answer to another technique which uses saturation in order to turn red into orange

Comment: Nearly there - only one problem I'm facing: `rgb2hsv(colorRGB);` you're passing a vec4, but the function `rgb2hsv` takes a vec3 as a param. Shader won't compile.

Comment: Update: `rgb2hsv(colorRGB.rgb);` duh! Except now it appears not to affect the image when I set the effect amount to +-0.25. Will fiddle around some more.

Comment: Error in the shader fixed. It may not affect your image because the part which selects the hue range to change may be too strict: please try to force weight to be 1.0, this will apply the effect to the whole image, not just to red hues. Also please try to use a bigger effect amount, like 0.5, 1.0 or even more.

Comment: Yup, I'll give those a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Fiddled around - no luck yet. I've posted my current iteration (including the weight forcibly set to 1.0). Maybe you can spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If I understand well what you are saying is that the image is not changin at all ... so let's do a simple test then, we will force maximum saturation everywhere, add `colorHSV.y = 1.0;` just before `highp vec3 finalColorRGB = hsv2rgb(colorHSV.rgb);` ... I am starting to think that the uniforms values would not be sent to the shader ... so they would all be zero ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88118/discussion-between-vb-overflow-and-remus).

Comment: @VB_overflow: Hi, do you think this condition is needed? `if (dist < -0.5) dist += 1.0;`, since hue is in range [0,1)

Comment: @saurabheights: yes this condition is needed because `dist = hue - SKIN_HUE;` can be negative since both `hue` and `SKIN_HUE` are in [0,1).
Note that the "hue distance" stored in `dist`is some kind of angle, so adding 1.0 does not change the hue (like adding 360° to an angle does not change it), so the +1 / -1 operations are done only to make sure `dist` is in [0,1( interval. If you would search for functions computing distance between angles, it would look a bit the same.
Probably this part could be optimized by using other GLSL instructions to avoid doing if tests (step & clamp maybe).

Comment: @VB_overflow: Ok, first of all, please do not use GL language, or if you do that keep it as a latter part of the answer. Currently, your answer is great and any optimisation will make it highly unreadable for any novice. Regarding my earlier query, here is why I mentioned it: a.) hue is [0,1). b.) Skin hue is 0.05, c.) hue-SkinHue = [-0.05, 0.95, ] which does not need second condition. Actually, leave it be. If someone wants to generalise this code for colour besides 0.05, the code will work right out of the box. :)

Comment: @saurabheights: yes what you suggest makes sense in the case of skin, but like you said I prefer to keep a generic version here, which would work for other colors with other hues

Comment: @VB_overflow thanks for sharing glsl shader, I've just used your method for RGB->HSV in my project and it worked like a charm.